# I want to show reason in user profile but show reason id in user profile

Tags: laravel

```
public function getreason(Request $request){

    $reasons = TradeReason::where('trade_id',$request->trade_id)->pluck("reason_id");

    $reasondisplay = Reason::where "$reasons", '=', 'id')->pluck("reason");

    return response() -> json($reasondisplay);
}
```

Its code just show only reason id but not show reason in user profile

Comment: Please show your view page code.

Comment: you are missing "(" and double inverted comma instead of single. `$reasondisplay = Reason::where ('$reasons', '=', 'id')->pluck("reason");`

Comment: $reasondisplay = Reason::where ('$reasons', '=', 'id')->pluck("reason"); I tried this, not show me reason

Comment: This is view page code of reason <div class="form-group col-sm-10">
            {!! Form::label('reason', 'Choose Reasons:') !!}
        {{Form::select('reason',$reasons,null, array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'reason[]','class'=>'selectpicker', 'data-width'=>'60%', 'data-live-search'=>'true' ))}}

        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not properly coded, So just replace your function with this code and use `whereIn()` method in place of `where`.

```
public function getreason(Request $request){

    $reasons = TradeReason::where('trade_id',$request->trade_id)->pluck("reason_id");

    $reasondisplay = Reason::whereIn('id',$reasons)->pluck("reason");

    return response()->json($reasondisplay);
}
```

Comment: Great. Please accept my answer and upvote too :) as an appreciation.

Comment: yes i want to upvote but its does'nt work, can you help me in this?

Comment: Just click on upside arrow beside my answer :) just easy way

Comment: Its not allow me

Comment: Ok leave it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are querying for an array with a id in `$reasondisplay`. You have to use `whereIn()` function to query a id in the array and get the reason.

```
public function getreason(Request $request){

    $reasons = TradeReason::where('trade_id',$request->trade_id)->pluck('reason_id');

    $reasondisplay = Reason::whereIn('id', $reasons)->pluck('reason');

    return response() -> json($reasondisplay);
}
```

You can refer to laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Column must me the `first` param in where function

```
public function getreason(Request $request){
    $reasons = TradeReason::where('trade_id',$request->trade_id)->first();
    $reason = "";
    if($reasons){
        $reasondisplay = Reason::find($reasons->reason_id)->first();
        if($reasondisplay){
            $reason = $reasondisplay->reason;
        }
    }
    return response()->json(["reason"=>$reason]);
}
```

Better you can [use relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

In TradeReason

```
public function reason()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\TradeReason','id','reason_id');
    //                                      ^      ^
    //                                      |      |____ 'local_key'
    //                                      |__'foreign_key'
}
```

In Controller

```
public function getreason(Request $request){
    $reason = "";
    $tr = TradeReason::where('trade_id',$request->trade_id)->with("reason")->first();
    return response()->json(["reason"=>$tr->reason->reason]);
    //                                       ^          ^
    //                                       |          |___Column Name
    //                                       |__Relation Name
}
```